# Getting gmail messages through gmail api gets slower

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I've tried getting the mail details but the response keeps getting slower and slower. I've used google api for listing the emails and looping throught the email ids to get the email details.

Here's the code:

```
async function listMessages(req: any, res: any, next: any) {
  const user = req.query.email;
  try {
    const userObj = await userRepository.findUserByEmail(user);
    if (!userObj) {
      res.status(404).send("User not found");
    } else {
      const userinfo = await userRepository.findUserByEmail(user);

      oAuth2Client = await setAuth(userinfo.dataValues.refreshToken);
      // Fetch a list of emails
      const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth: oAuth2Client });
      const response = await gmail.users.messages.list({
        userId: "me",
      });
      const emails = response.data.messages;

      const emailArray: any = [];

      if (emails && emails.length > 0) {
        console.log("List of emails:");

        // Use a Promise-based approach to fetch email details for each email
        const fetchEmailDetailsPromises = emails.map((email: any) => {
          return getMessageDetails(email.id, user);
        });

        Promise.all(fetchEmailDetailsPromises)
          .then((emailDetailsArray) => {
            // Now you have an array of email details
            emailDetailsArray.forEach((emailDetail: any) => {
              emailArray.push(emailDetail);
            });

            // Send the response with email details
            res.json(emailArray);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error fetching email details:", error);
            // Handle the error here
            res.status(500).json({ error: "Error fetching email details" });
          });
      } else {
        console.log("No emails found.");
        res.json(emailArray); // Send an empty array if no emails are found
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return next(err);
  }
}
```

```
const getMessageDetails = async (messageId: any, user: any) => {
  try {
    // Authorize using the access token
    const userinfo = await userRepository.findUserByEmail(user);

    oAuth2Client = await setAuth(userinfo.dataValues.refreshToken);
    // Fetch a list of emails
    const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth: oAuth2Client });

    // Fetch email details
    const response = await gmail.users.messages.get({
      userId: "me",
      id: messageId,
    });

    const emailDetails = response.data;

    return emailDetails;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching email details:", error);
  }
};
```

The emailDetail is received very slow and takes 20-25 seconds. Please suggest some alternate ways to get the email details,plus I need comlete details.

Comment: Its a free api even if it went faster you would probably start getting throttled